# How many $4$ digit numbers such that $4$ is always left of $1$ can be formed? (Repetition is NOT allowed)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose that you are given a set

$$A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

- How many $4$ digit numbers such that $4$ is always right of $1$ can be formed? (Repetition is NOT allowed)

**My attempt:**

$$41\_ \space \_$$

There are $3!$ ways to permutate them and ${4}\choose{2}$ ways to pick 2 numbers out of remaining $4$ numbers.

Can you assist me?

Regards

Comment: Do $1$ and $4$ have to occur?

Comment: Does 4 have to be directly to the left of 1, or would 4213 work?

Comment: Doesn't $4231$ meet the criteria?  You can't get this by permuting $41,3$ and $2.$ $(3$ elements, one with two digits.)

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes, exactly.

Comment: See the updated question, please.

Comment: @TheoC. Yes, that would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the places for $4$ and $1$ and $4 \cdot 3=12$ ways to choose $2$ from the other $4$ digits and thus:
$$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 12=6 \cdot 12=72$$
possible choices